# How to locate this button with blank in class name?

Tags: javascript, selenium

Open this link: https://search.jd.com/Search?keyword=dfa%20dfgfg&enc=utf-8&wq=dfa%20dfgfg&pvid=219dc22c6de24899b71b5111f1cb81de, how to locate the button"搜索": 搜索

dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.cw-icon")) does not work.

Comment: `JavaScript` is no `Java`! Spaces in CSS `class` attribute are used to separate multiple values....

Comment: Sorry. I'm a beginner for web testing. Try to use selenium in java. Manythings are difficult for me by now. I need study step by step. thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this with buttons,anchors or anything.This will console the first element having blank in its class name.

```js
console.log($("a[class*='blank']").eq(0).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="xyz.com" class="blank">Hello</a>
```

Comment: thx. I modified my question. I found js in this page. Do not know how to handle it.   window.jdpts={};jdpts._st=new Date().getTime();
window.pageConfig={compatible:false, searchType:0, pSource:'search_pc', price_pdos_off:0};
window.QUERY_KEYWORD='dfa dfgfg';
window.SEARCH={};
window.searchUnit={resizeShopbox:function(e,d){var f=0;switch(e){case 1:case 2:f=145;break;case 3:f=75;break;case 4:f=80;break;default:break}f&&$("#shopboxIFrame").css("height",f).show();typeof(d)=="string"&&(new Image().src=d)}};

Comment: You'll need to edit more and make it clearer I still interpret it from your question that it is java script task.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `driver.findElement.By.cssSelector`?

Your css selector is correct, as you can run in console as `document.querySelector('button.button.cw-icon')` so the problem should be on your Selenium implementation.

Try to query anything by css, like a `button` only or something.

My guess is: the DOM isn't ready yet or you're not calling the method properly.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe"); WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver(); ... dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.cw-icon"));~thx~

Answer (score 0):

If i am right, you are not clicking the element. Try:

```
dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.cw-icon")).click();
```

If that still doesn't work try using xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'cw-icon')]/i")).click();
```